# Update an MST after removing 3 edges from the graph

Tags: algorithm, graph, computer-science

> Let `G(V,E)` an undirected and connected graph with the weight function `w`. We are given `T`, an MST of `G`. Now we remove `e1, e2, e3` from `G` (**which also appear in `T`**) and get a new graph, `G'`. Describe an efficient algorithm to find an MST of `G'`.

My intuition tells me that we can throw those `3` edges and run Prim algorithm for `G'` starting from `T-{e1, e2,e3}`.

Is my intuition correct? Could help me formulate this (Or suggest another approach)?

Answer (score 1):

Prim's algorithm grows a tree T in G from a single vertex by adding edges, but removing an edge from T makes it disconnected, so you cannot use this as partial input for the algorithm.

You can however use Kruskal's agorithm, which grows a forest T until it is connected. Deleting one edge of T from the G requires one new step of the algorithm. The proof is along the lines of the proof of correctness for the algorithm itself.

Answer (score 1):

You can solve it using Kruskal's Algorithm where you start traversing the edges which have a weight >= max(e1,e2,e3) from the set { S-{e1,e2,e3} }. Before this step the graph would have all the edges you need.